# How do we overcome ambiguity when using the particle "wohl"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, particle

The particle *"wohl"* can be used in two different meanings:

> ***"Auf GL&U kann man sich vorzüglich über Deutsch informieren."***
>
> - *"Das ist wohl wahr."* - This is **probably** true.
> - *"Das ist wohl wahr."* - This is **very** true.

By what means do we differentiate one from the other meaning? What would be an appropriate way to avoid misunderstandings when using *"wohl"* in writing, or when translating a written text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In speech we have the possibility to emphasize the meaning. Stress *Das* and sustain *wohl* a bit to signify intensification and your accordance.

In written text it is hard to avoid misunderstanding, though you can indicate the connotation in the sentences before and after. I think in your example the reader would assume the second variation, because - imho - it is more common.

If you have a sentence in which it is hard to differentiate the connotation, you have two possibilities to clarify the meaning

You replace *wohl*

> 1. Das ist wahrscheinlich wahr. *(probably)*
> 2. Das ist durchaus wahr. *(true)*

or rephrase the sentence.

> 1. Das wird wohl so sein. *(obviously probably)*
> 2. Das kann man wohl sagen. *(obviously true)*

Edit:
Regarding the translation there are three scenarios

1. You are able to get the meaning from the surrounding text.

   > "Das ist wohl wahr, aber ich glaube es nicht wirklich."

   *But I don't believe it* alludes to *probably*. In this case it is easy to translate it.

   It's much more complicated, if the surrounding text still don't clarify the connotation.

   > "Das ist wohl wahr, aber sicherlich nur wenn man ... ."

   Then you have to go with possibility 2 or 3.
2. Use the word which is more likely or common in context.
3. Leave it out if the word is negligible.

But note: In your example it is necessary if you want to emphasize *probably*, because *That's true* indicates the second variation.

Conclusion:
It's hardly possible to translate a word like *wohl* if the context does not clarify its meaning. I propose to leave it out if possible. If you get the feeling leaving out gives the wrong connotation then add the more likely word.